# ASP.Net MVC4 JSTREE integration

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jstree

I am trying to integrate the `jstree_pre1.0_stable` Version to my ASP.Net Mvc4.0 Project...

here are the steps i followed

1. I have Added `jquery.jstree.js` file in the script folder
2. i have included the `jquery-1.7.1.min.js` and `jquery.jstree.js` in the view Page.

   and added following code below the script files
   (equipment_tree is a sample unordered List)

   ```
   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#equipment_tree").jstree();
   });
   ```

When i run ,i  get error in the line`$("#equipment_tree").jstree()`;

Unhandled exception at line 102, column 9 in

`0x800a01b6 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method`.

But if i do the same steps in ASP.NET MVC3 ..it works fine,,I am using IE8 as my browser..

Can anyone help me in this regard.Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Sounds like the path to jstree.js may be incorrect.. Have you checked this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the scripts are loaded properly? Did you insert the JS references in the HTML View directly or are you using script bundles in your BundleConfig.cs? Check this first.

If you could paste here your code it would be easier to spot the problem. Or even if you could try this in jsfiddle and paste the link here.

Maybe try pasting the generated HTML source code here.

**Anyway, there might be several reasons for jstree method not firing:**

- jquery and/or jstree might not be included at all
- jquery might be included after jstree
- your js reference paths might be incorrect (as Steve mentioned)
- maybe you screwed up with script bundles somehow (it happens to me sometimes)

From what you wrote it seems to me that you use Visual Studio to debug JavaScript. I advise you try and see with **Firebug** or **Chrome web developer tools** if all your scripts are included at all, because if you did a mistake with bundles (bad virtual path for example) it might be that your scripts are not included at all, but you might think they are.

Hopefully that helped.